# Alert on moving comment discussion to chat

Tags: discussion, chat, comments

If comments on a post turn into discussion, the system pops up an option to continue the discussion in chat. Some things to be aware of:

1. The word "continue". It doesn't move previous comments to chat, they remain on the post. A moderator is likely to delete them, though, as post cleanup if they are copied in a chat room.
2. The system copies only **some** of the comments to the chat room. It appears that the copied comments will be those only of the most recent two commenters. So if there is a three-way discussion and one participant opts to continue in chat, only the comments of that person and the most recent other commenter will get copied to the room.
3. I'm not aware of a way to manually add uncopied previous comments to the room.
4. There's an option to move the entire comment thread to (a different) chat (which might include comments not part of the "discussion"), but that can be done only once on a post.
5. Chat rooms get automatically closed after being inactive for a period (I believe a week). If it is merely frozen, you can still find it and read it. A moderator can unfreeze it for additional commenting. But if the room contains less than 15 postings by less than 2 users, the room gets automatically deleted from the system. So a short discussion moved to chat will not have a long shelf life. If the content of the discussion is important to preserve, continuing it in chat might not be the way to do it.

Comment: To manually add uncopied comments, you can copy-paste their links into the chat room. They'll be one-boxed, and will remain even after the original comments are deleted (provided the message remains unedited). Moderators can undelete auto-deleted chatrooms as well as unfreezing auto-frozen ones.